# @RequestBody after reading input stream in inteceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to have Spring map up a request body to a POJO using the @RequestBody annotation.

I am getting an error

> "Required request body content is missing: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter@4c3bfe22

as I have already called getInputStream on the request from an interceptor earlier for validation.

I have extended the HttpServletRequestWrapper and overridden the getInputStream method to return a ServletInputStream that gets the data from a String cache that was created on the original read.

When debugging, I can call getInputStream as many times as I like in the interceptor but Spring still is unable to map up the POJO. When I comment out the line of code that reads in the body originally in the inteceptor, Spring can map the POJO fine.

I'm not overly clear on how Spring maps up the data to a POJO, have I missed something?

Thanks

Comment: Show your code!  Sounds like some code sentence is missing.

Comment: Are you decorating with HttpServletRequestWrapper in a filter or inside the Interceptor ?

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek Thank you, I was doing it from within the Interceptor but after your comment I checked and realised I needed to do it within a filter.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue after Klaus' comment regarding filter vs interceptor.

For anyone else finding this problem, you can only do this from a filter and not an interceptor.